# Pandas create new column in DataFrame based on values in two other DataFrame's

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, join, merge

I have three DataFrames. I want to create an extra column in the first one based on the values in the other two. The first step is to match the 'name' column from df1 to the one in df2. This will then know which kind of shift they worked. The idea is then to create a new column in df1 using the shift rate for the relevant date and bonus by matching the date columns in df1 and df3 as well as getting the rate for that day from the appropriate column of df3.

Three complications are:

1. There is no column for the regular rate in df3
2. The regular rate will be 3 on every date
3. The bonus's names from df2 don't match the columns of df3 exactly just the first and last letter with a hyphen in between

Code:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20190101', periods=4)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
        [dates[0], 'Tim'],
        [dates[1], 'Micheal'],
        [dates[2], 'David'],
        [dates[3], 'Tim']]),
        columns=['Date', 'Name'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
        ['David', 'none'],
        ['Tim', 'sales'],
        ['Michael', 'overtime']]),
        columns=['Name', 'bonus'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
        [dates[0], 8, 10],
        [dates[1], 4, 5],
        [dates[2], 4, 5],
        [dates[3], 4, 5]]),
        columns=['Date', 's-s', 'o-t'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
        [dates[0], 'Tim', 8],
        [dates[1], 'Micheal', 5],
        [dates[2], 'David', 3],
        [dates[3], 'Tim', 4]]),
        columns=['Date', 'Name', 'Rate'])
```

Comment: Is "Micheal" a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Merge `df1` and `df2` on the `Name` column to get the `bonus` for each worker.
2. Merge the result with `df3` on the `Date` column to get the shift rates for each worker and date.
3. Set the `Rate` column to the computed shift rate for each worker and date using `apply()`.

Like this:

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Name', how='left')

merged = pd.merge(merged, df3, on='Date', how='left')

merged['Rate'] = merged.apply(lambda row: row['o-t'] if row['bonus'] == 'overtime' else (row['s-s'] if row['bonus'] == 'sales' else 3), axis=1)

df1['Rate'] = merged['Rate']

print(df1)
```

Notice, if you do not have an error in the data (`Micheal` and `Michael` from `df2`), then the output is:

```
        Date     Name  Rate
0 2019-01-01      Tim     8
1 2019-01-02  Micheal     3
2 2019-01-03    David     3
3 2019-01-04      Tim     4
```

If you have a typo, after fix:

```
        Date     Name  Rate
0 2019-01-01      Tim     8
1 2019-01-02  Michael     5
2 2019-01-03    David     3
3 2019-01-04      Tim     4
```

Comment: Have you tested your code? This doesn't follow the described logic…

Comment: The rows should be calculated such that they get the rate on the relevant dates. Tim get's £8 on 01/01/19 because that was the sales bonus for that date. He got the same bonus on 04/01/19 but only got £4 as the rate had changed for that bonus on that day. Michael gets £5 on 02/01/19 because that is the rate for the overtime bonus on that date. David gets £3 on 03/01/19 this is the flat rate that everyone receives if no bonus is paid.

Comment: guys, the logic is clear, nothing to discuss. the real question is that there is a typo in the data that breaks the desired answer

Answer (score 1):

Using a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
out = df1.merge(df2, how='left').merge(
 (df3.rename(columns={'s-s': 'sales', 'o-t': 'overtime'})
     .melt('Date', var_name='bonus', value_name='Rate')
 ), on=['Date', 'bonus'], how='left'
).fillna({'Rate': 3}).drop(columns='bonus')
```

Or, for in place modification of `df1`:

```
df1['Rate'] = (df1.merge(df2, how='left')
                  .merge(df3.rename(columns={'s-s': 'sales', 'o-t': 'overtime'})
                            .melt('Date', var_name='bonus', value_name='Rate'),
                         on=['Date', 'bonus'], how='left')
                  .fillna({'Rate': 3})['Rate']
              )
```

Alternative using [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup):

```
tmp = df1.merge(df2, how='left').merge(df3, how='left')

idx, cols = pd.factorize(tmp['bonus'].map({'sales': 's-s', 'overtime': 'o-t'}))

df1['Rate'] = np.where(idx>-1, tmp.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(tmp)), idx], 3)
```

Output:

```
        Date     Name  Rate
0 2019-01-01      Tim     8
1 2019-01-02  Michael     5
2 2019-01-03    David     3
3 2019-01-04      Tim     4
```

Comment: look at the df2, Michael is not equal to Micheal from df1, you output is wrong

Comment: Exactly, the correct suggestion in the answer is exactly what the OP is waiting for.  But what moderators and highly rated users are fighting against. I'm just following a role model ;D